# How can the compiler optimization affect the data loading speed?

Tags: c++, performance

I have tested three C++ program codes which **load the data from the memory to CPU, do the simple + or x operations** (count the time here) and then report the result. These three codes have the same structure but with different data types (int,double,float).

The testing result is: The time is 2x when the data size is 2x for both three codes.

However, I have the following observations.

Observation 1: the time is 2x slower when the optimization is not used. However, it is strange since the loading time (bottleneck) should not be affected by the compiler.

Observation 2: the time for double type program code is roughly 2x faster than both the int and float type program codes when no compiler optimization is added into it and the data size is fixed (256MB,512MB,1024MB,2048MB,4096MB). It is also strange, since double should be the slowest one.

Remark for Observation 2: The time for both three codes are similar when I add the compiler optimization (O,O2,O3).

The attched Code is here:

```
int main()
{
     float value;
     double totalTimeDifference;

     const int numberOFElements=178956970; //4GB for 6 arrays in total 
     float*FLOAT_Array_one=new float[numberOFElements];
     float*FLOAT_Array_two=new float[numberOFElements];
     float*FLOAT_Array_three=new float[numberOFElements];
     float*FLOAT_Array_four=new float[numberOFElements];
     float*FLOAT_Array_five=new float[numberOFElements];
     float*FLOAT_Array=new float[numberOFElements];

     srand(time(NULL));
     for(int i=0;i<numberOFElements;i++)
     {
         FLOAT_Array_one[i]=rand()% 400;
         FLOAT_Array_two[i]=rand()% 400;
         FLOAT_Array_four[i]=rand()% 400;
         FLOAT_Array_five[i]=rand()% 400;
     }

     timeval tim1;
     timeval tim2;
     gettimeofday(&tim1,NULL);

     //****************************//
     for(int i=0;i<numberOFElements;i++)
     {
         FLOAT_Array[i]=FLOAT_Array_one[i]+FLOAT_Array_two[i];
     }
     //****************************//

     //****************************//
     for(int i=0;i<numberOFElements;i++)
     {
         FLOAT_Array_three[i]=FLOAT_Array_four[i]*FLOAT_Array_five[i];
     }
     //****************************//
     gettimeofday(&tim2,NULL);

     double t1=tim1.tv_sec+(tim1.tv_usec/1000000.0);
     double t2=tim2.tv_sec+(tim2.tv_usec/1000000.0);

     for(int i=0;i<numberOFElements;i++)
     {
         if(i%2==0)
             value=value+FLOAT_Array[i]+FLOAT_Array_three[i];
         else
             value=value-FLOAT_Array[i]-FLOAT_Array_three[i];
     }

     totalTimeDifference=t2-t1; 
     cout<<value<<endl;
     cout<<totalTimeDifference<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Devil's in the details. Without seeing the code (and prob the generated assembly), we could only make wild guesses about what's actually going on.

Comment: The timing for non-optimized code is uninteresting, because you tell the compiler "Don't bother to make it fast". So it doesn't, and the program can contain lots of unnecessary code..

Comment: I have added the code here. It is the float version.

Comment: Load speed is affected by -O0 because there will be more stores and loads (to/from the stack, where it will put all locals, rather than allocating registers)

Answer (score 1):

A few educated guesses:

1. Since you are doing arithmetic operations in your "loading" between the two time checks, it may be employing SSE streaming floating-point math instructions only when optimized.  This should result in a significant speedup.
2. If you are on a 64-bit OS, memory access for two half words takes more time than one whole one.  On a 64-bit program, a float takes only 32-bits, and subsequent accesses to half words take more time than a single access to a whole word.  The part I don't understand about that, however, is how optimizations are able to get around this.